How to do identity verification in OneSignal using Cordova
I am using Cordova OneSignal for push notifications.
As in: cordova plugins add onesignal-cordova-plugin
Currently, I am able to use window.plugins.OneSignal.login(external_id) to set the user's external id.
However, I need to use window.plugins.OneSignal.setExternalUserId(external_id, external_id_hash) instead because that function allows support for identity verification.
But it is undefined. Since the plugin has not defined setExternalUserId, how am I supposed to do identity verification?
I even looked through the plugin's source code on github, and setExternalUserId was not defined anywhere despite being mentioned in the docs.

As I see, you have already opened an issue on their github, this is good!

It seems like version 5+ of the SDK currently does not support identity verification.
Switching to version 3.3.3 will solve this issue.
